# Is there a googlebot equivalent for RSS feeds?

Tags: google, google-search-console, rss

I have a lot of feeds generated on my pages - and it seems to let them go to waste (Googlebot does not seem to see them). The RSS feeds display correctly in the pages when viewed through a browser, so I know they are working correctly.

Is there a way where I can somehow make the RSS feeds 'discoverable' by the world? (so I can drive traffic to my site?)

Answer (score 2):

You can submit RSS feeds to Google Webmaster Tools as well as the equivalents at Bing and Yahoo. I would also suggest subscribing to them yourself in a Google Reader account - that way Google will regularly check the feeds for updates.

Note that none of this guarantees your content will be indexed. It's best to ensure the content is easily accessible from the site itself without RSS.

Answer (score 1):

Have you ever tried feed search engines or where you can submit your feeds, like technoarti

Comment: Are there any general-purpose feed search engines like Technorati? Even though Technorati has sections for other genres, like sports and entertainment, its user-base still seems to be primarily geeks and techies. But perhaps that's just the nature of news feeds.

Answer (score 0):

if the rss feeds are referred to in the head section of the html or linked to in the body of the html google will discover them. (you can use: [site:yourdomain.com inurl:rss] to look if some of them were indexed)

and/or you can submit RSS as a sitemap kinda file via google webmaster tools, more about that see http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/10/using-rssatom-feeds-to-discover-new.html

but as they are no landing pages and most of the time duplicate content google won't show them in the SERPS (since 2007) see http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2007/12/taking-feeds-out-of-our-web-search.html (most of the times, there are still exceptions i.e. a site: search)